# Run Kivy on Android

Tags: python, kivy

So, I can run kivy example files (like pong) on my Android but I can't run [my own app](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8ymypaz37m0xi9z/AAAXES7UPCvuEjmzM8HbsjRGa?dl=0), it just saying "Hello World!".

I don't understand, if someone can help me.

This is my Python code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Config.set('graphics','width','360')
Config.set('graphics','height','640')

class Mot(Widget):
    def mot(self):
        test = 0

    def bouger(self):



class WorDown(App):
    def build(self):
        return Mot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WorDown().run()
```

Next my Kivy code :

```
#:kivy 1.0

<Mot>:
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (255, 0, 0)
            Rectangle:
                size: (360,640)
                pos: self.pos

    Label:
        text: 'WorDown'
        center_x: root.width / 2
```

And my android.txt :

```
title=WorDown
author=pito
orientation=portrait
```

So I put these three files in a folder in the Kivy folder of my Android Phone. And when I run Kivy launcher, and click on "WorDown", Kivy Launcher runs the app but crashes just 3 seconds after...

And I don't understand why, because on my Windows Computer, it runs very well!

Comment: Show us some code first. Also, what is your sequence of operations when building and running?

Comment: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: Thank you, but like I'm french, I don't understand all the Kivy docs , so can you help me by changing or testing my code please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look at the python code you included. In `class Mot` you have

```
def bouger(self):
```

but nothing in the function body.

Do you really don't have anything in the body? Your code shouldn't even run on your computer then, so I guess you just didn't post everything.

If you are sure that the code in this function is not causing the crash, just write "pass" in the function body, so that it doesn't confuse other readers.

Answer (score 0):

you could follow the code
*main.py*

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='WorDown' )

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your code after removing 7 and 8 lines of your code.

Comment: Please be more specific about which lines they should remove and why that would solve this problem.